# How to connect to a different Database from Rails APP

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to connect to a different Database (php_db) from a rails app.

currently App has mysql Database(ror_db). Both Databases are on the same server.

I have some requirement ,where i have to insert some records from rails app to php_db.

I have used below code to do that.
Not sure how far it is secure.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter  => "mysql",
    :host     => "localhost",
    :username => "xxxxxx",
    :password => "xxxxxx",
    :database => "php_db"
)
sql_update = "INSERT INTO cxv_journal(trans_no, reference,tran_date,event_date,doc_date) VALUES (2,2,'xxxx-xx-xx','xxxx-xx-xx','xxxx-xx-xx')"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_update)
ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
config =YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root,"config","database.yml")) 
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config['production'])
```

Appreciate any suggestion for more optimized solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could also use this gem https://github.com/ankane/multiverse

Comment: Are you using environment variables?